# I'm not able to run my flutter project on android (emulator & real device). How can I fix it?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-android

Whenever I try to run my flutter project on either emulator or real device, it always shows me an error but I'm able to run the same project on web(Chrome).

I tried to resolve this problem myself in many ways but couldn't. This image can describe my problem clearly.[This is the screenshot of the major problem that comes to me while running the flutter app on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiOpM.png)

Comment: It's often encouraged not to post images unless unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

1. delete .gradle file.
2. run flutter clean.
3. run flutter pub get.

it should work.